# "Lots and lots of...two different uncountable nouns"

Tags: verb-agreement

I'm writing a story for little children and would really appreciate some help with the following sentence:

> "There was lots and lots of red, and lots and lots of blue."

Is that correct? Or should it be "there were"?

Comment: It’s just *was*.  Read it as “There was [lots and lots of] red, and [there was] [lots and lots of] blue.”

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/69652, http://english.stackexchange.com/a/70077, http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77093 and the things they reference and link to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying merely blue or red as an object rather than a modifier,'was'shall be used.

There **was** loads and loads of blue (colour) and loads and loads of red (colour).

However if there were an object that blue and red were modifying and the object was more than one in number, we would use 'were'.

*There were loads and loads of blue books and loads and loads of red books.*

The only time you would use a colour name in plural would be when referring to shades:

*There were many greens to choose from.* which is an informal way of actually saying 
*There were many hues/shades of greens to choose from.*

or in a metaphorical use of the colour.

*I have the blues.*"

Comment: I guess shall sit and re-do it all at once..when I am not multi-tasking..:)